# Django's template variable gets interpreted as HTML

Tags: html, django, templates, django-templates

When `DEBUG=True` a variable containing HTML is just printed in the template and **not** interpeted as HTML. This is the correct behavior.

On the other hand, when `DEBUG=False` (just changing this) the variable's content is interpreted as HTML and I cannot understand why. I'm not using the `safe` filter.

My template is as follows:

```
  <pre id="copy-source-{{ forloop.counter }}">
    <code>{{ code }}</code>
  </pre>
```

In one case, `code` happens to be HTML code, specifically:

```
<a href="blabla"><img src="bblabla" /></a>
```

and the page displays the image instead of the code, even if it's inside a pre-code!?

Comment: what django version are you using?

Comment: @alecxe: 1.5.1, sorry for not having included that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{var_containing_html}}
{% endautoescape %}
```

I hope this will help.
Good luck.

P.S. Also see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape)

Comment: I thought it was working but it's not. I'll update the question with more details.

Comment: Did you try {% autoescape on %}? Then `<` and `>` symbols will be escaped and look like `&lt;` and `&gt;` and will not be interpreted as html by the browser, so users wiil be able to see the code.

Comment: Yes, and surprisingly it does not work. I still see the image. If instead I turn `DEBUG` off I see the code! I'm become crazy here...